# Shiny selectInput doesn't react to tab selection

Tags: shiny, leaflet, shinyapps, r-leaflet, bs4dash

Here is my problem, I have a couple of tabs and I'm trying to update a map according to a choice in the `selectInput()` function.
The `select` option in `inputSelect()` is activated and points to `Los Angeles` which should activate the `ObserveEvent()` or `Observe()` function but it doesn't when clicking on the `Map` tab for the first time.
However, I realized that the `setView()` function doesn't update itself when clicking on the second tab even if I have the `selected` option set in `selectInput()`.
I want a `setView()` that reacts to the `selected` option on the first click on the tab.
The `selectize` option doesn't bring any difference.
Here is an example of what I would like to replicate.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui = bs4DashPage(
  h1('Exemple'),
  br(),
  bs4TabSetPanel(id = 'tabs',
                 side = 'left',
                 bs4TabPanel(tabName = 'First tab',
                             active = TRUE,
                             'Here is some text'),
                 bs4TabPanel(tabName = 'Second tab',
                             active = FALSE,
                             fluidRow(bs4Card(title = 'Inputs',     
                                              solidHeader = TRUE,
                                              width = 2,
                                              closable = FALSE,
                                              selectInput(inputId = 'city',
                                                          label = 'Select a city',
                                                          choices = c('New York','Los Angeles','Seattle'),
                                                          selected = 'Los Angeles',
                                                          selectize = TRUE)),
                                      bs4Card(title = "Map",
                                              width = 10,
                                              leafletOutput('map'))
                                      )))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -95.7129,lat = 37.0902, zoom = 3)
  })

  observeEvent(input$city, {
    if(input$city == 'New York'){
      lon <- -74.0060
      lat <- 40.7128
    } else if(input$city == 'Los Angeles'){
      lon <- -118.2437
      lat <- 34.0522
    } else{
      lon <- -122.3321
      lat <- 47.6062
    }
    leafletProxy('map') %>%
      setView(lng = lon, lat = lat, zoom = 5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about `observeEvent(list(input$tabs, input$city), {......` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work but thank you I will have some usage for this line of code in another project ;-)